# If Statement is Ignored?

Tags: php, customization, advanced-custom-fields

I’m trying to update a boolean custom field based on whether a post has ‘expired’.

A post is considered expired when its publish date exceeds 30 days. To check this, I am retrieving the post publish date using `get_the_date()` and adding 30 days to it. Then I check whether this new date is greater than or equal to the present date.

However, the if statement used to compare the dates doesn’t seem to get triggered at all. I checked a post which was published today, and the Boolean True / False field is false. I checked a post published a year ago, and it’s still false (expected: true).

Can anyone help me figure out what’s going on? If you have any suggestions as to how I can improve this, please feel free to mention it.

Kind regards.

```
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=is_listing_expired', 'acf_listing_expiry');
function acf_listing_expiry($field) {

    $start_date_string = get_field('listing_start_date'); //Get the start date value

    $date_format = "Ymd";

    $listing_date = DateTime::createFromFormat($date_format, get_the_date('Ymd', null)); //Convert to a DateTime object
    $modify_amount = "+" . get_field('days_till_expiry') . " days"; //Get the days till expiry value, minimum value is 2

    $new_date = $listing_date->modify($modify_amount); //Get the end date

    $current_date = date($date_format);

    //Check if the date has reached 
    if($new_date <= $current_date) {
        $field['default_value'] = true;
        return $field;
    } else {
        $field['default_value'] = false;
    }
    $field['default_value'] = false;
    return $field;
}
```

Comment: You're just setting the default value, but if the post has been saved with a value then the default value isn't going to be used. You'd want to change the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** Turns out I was trying to make a comparison between a DateTime object and the date() function of PHP. When I switched date() to DateTime the comparison was fine.